# how to add looping from putextra?

Tags: java, android

i want create 49 case, but it to much coding if i use case 0 - 49.
i need simple coding using loop for my switch case.

this my source code

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    int topicNumber = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.TOPIC_NUMBER, 0);
        switch (topicNumber) {
            case 0:
                profil_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you cannot define switch cases in a loop

Comment: I'm sure your code needs refactoring if you have to write 49 cases

Comment: so i must write 49case without loop ?

Comment: You can use a loop!

Comment: Can you add more cases ?

Comment: @Xenolion : how ? please

Comment: If your drawable sources are different, you can simply add their id's to the list. Then you can use them according to `topicNumber` value.

Comment: Like : `profil_image.setImageResource(yourImageList.get(topicNumber));`

Comment: If all your cases are similar, maybe you could put the image resources in an integer array, and then use `profil_image.setImageResource(drawablesArray[topicNumber]);`

Comment: @CagriYalcin Now we gotta decide what to use: array or list :P

Comment: @A.K.S.H. take your pick :) Or maybe an `ArrayList<>()`

Comment: @A.K.S.H. its work , thank you , i just add array like this static int[] images = {R.drawable.img0,R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2};

Comment: @CagriYalcin thanks

Comment: I have answered your question @AchmadRivaldi

Comment: Anyone who downvoted my answer should consider upvoting it its edited.

Comment: @AchmadRivaldi I'll post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an integer array to store image resources:

```
int[] drawablesArray = {
        R.drawable.img0,
        R.drawable.img1,
        R.drawable.img2,
        ...
};
```

Then use the switch variable as index:

`profil_image.setImageResource(drawablesArray[topicNumber]);`

Answer (score -1):

You have to first add all your images in an int array as follows, I assume all of them are drawable from the drawable folder they has to be 50 as your logic.
 (NOTE *You can repeat a drawable twice as follows*)
 **Do as follows:**

```
int [] images={R.drawable.bg, R.drawable.another_one,R.drawable.more_another,......};
```

Then without a loop you can just do like this do not use arraylist just use int array for performance:

```
profil_image.setImageResource(images[topicNumber]);
```